# How to report custom istream failures

Tags: c++, exception, customization, istream

I would like to use operator>>() for reading linear algebraic data from console. I would like operator>>() to behave like it does for build-in data (like int, double), but I also wish to report appropriate messages when input cannot be parsed.

I’ve finally constructed a ‘custom_istream_failure’ class, but all together it was quite a hassle. Now I wonder: Is this the way to go, or does another mechanism exist for this purpose? Is this in the spirit of the standard?

I’ve included a small test program which reports a custom failure in the ‘expect’ function. Additionally I’ve included the ‘custom_istream_failure.h’ header file this question is about.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "custom_istream_failure.h"

struct vector_t { int x, y, z; };

bool expect(std::istream& is, char e)
{
    if (is.get() != e)
    {
        custom_istream_failure(is) 
            << "Expected '" << e << '\'' 
            << and_throw;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

std::istream& operator>>(
    std::istream& is, vector_t& v)
{
    expect(is, '(') &&
    (is >> v.x)     &&
    expect(is, ',') &&
    (is >> v.y)     &&
    expect(is, ',') &&
    (is >> v.z)     &&
    expect(is, ')');
    return is;
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        std::cin.exceptions(std::istream::failbit);
        vector_t vector;
        std::cin >> vector;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#ifndef CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE
#define CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

class custom_istream_failure
    : protected std::stringstream
{
public:
    explicit custom_istream_failure(std::istream& is)
        : m_is(is)
    {}
    custom_istream_failure& operator<<(
        custom_istream_failure& 
            (*pf)(custom_istream_failure&))
    {
        return ((*pf)(*this));
    }
#define CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(D) \
    custom_istream_failure& operator<<(D) \
    { \
        *static_cast<std::stringstream*>(this) << v; \
         return *this; \
    }
    CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(bool v)
    CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(short v)
    CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(unsigned short v)
    CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(int v)
    CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(unsigned int v)
    CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(long v)
    CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(unsigned long v)
    CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(long long v)
    CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(unsigned long long v)
    CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(float v)
    CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(double v)
    CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(long double v)
    CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(void* v)
    CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(std::streambuf* v)
    CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(
        std::ostream& (*v)(std::ostream&))
    CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(
        std::ios& (*v)(std::ios&))
    CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(
        std::ios_base& (*v)(std::ios_base&))
    CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(char v)
    CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(signed char v)
    CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(unsigned char v)
    CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(const char* v)
    CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(const signed char* v)
    CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP(const unsigned char*v);
#undef CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE_SOP
private:
    std::istream& m_is;
    friend custom_istream_failure& and_throw(
        custom_istream_failure&);
};

inline custom_istream_failure& and_throw(
    custom_istream_failure& cif)
{
    try { throw std::ios_base::failure(cif.str()); }
    catch (...)
    { 
        cif.m_is.setstate(std::ios::failbit, true);
    }
    return (cif);
}

#endif // CUSTOM_ISTREAM_FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to just make the input operator for your type handle the error conditions (example below).  If a user wants exceptions to be thrown on error the `setstate` will trigger an appropriate exception.  And for users that don't want exceptions will just check the status of the input stream in the usual manner.

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, vector_t &v) {
    char c;
    if (is >> c && c == '(') {
        int x = 0;
        if (is >> x >> c && c == ',') {
            int y = 0;
            if (is >> y >> c && c == ',') {
                int z = 0;
                if (is >> z >> c && c == ')') {
                    v = {x, y, z};
                    return is;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    return is;
}
```

Comment: using something like std::cin.good() to check the failbit, and throwing an exception if the istream is broken beyond repair

Comment: @Brandon Why not use failbit to check failbit?

Comment: Good() is a stronger check, it also checks the bad bit and eof bit. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/

Comment: @Brandon That was sort of my point. `good` checkes more things, but if you are only looking  for `failbit` you should check for `failbit`. In an application usage you need to know why it's failing so you can do the appropriate recovery.  In my answer both eof and failbit might be set. If eof is set then you know why failbit is too. No need to try another input of some other custom type.

Comment: started like Bo R (note the 'm_is.setstate' in 'and_throw'), but then the user gets the message 'ios_base::failbit set: iostream stream error', which is not really descriptive. For when e.g. an '(' is expected, I wanted to customize the message. It does work, but the solution feels unnecesary big. Does a lighter approach exist?